# Rails 5 Securing Action Cable with redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, actioncable

What can I do to secure socket connection in rails 5 with redis and action Cable?

What configuration we can add in

> config/redis.rb

to add password authentication in Redis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe these are the only options exposed for now:

```
development: &development
  :url: redis://localhost:6379
  :host: localhost
  :port: 6379
  :timeout: 1
  :inline: true
test: *development
production: &production
  :url: redis://{redis_host}:{redis_port}/
  :host: {redis_host}
  :port: {redis_port}
  :password: {redis_password}
  :inline: true
  :timeout: 1
```

Answer (score 5):

```
production:
  url: redis://:{redis_auth}@{redis_host}:{redis_port}/1
```

Notice ':' before {redis_auth}.

Comment: I get a  URI::InvalidURIError(bad URI(is not URI?) error when using this approach. Does this mean that there are particular characters that can't be in the redis password?

Comment: @apod I believe there can be such problems

Comment: BTW, if you password includes any characters that are not URI-safe (for me, the / character was the culprit), the solution is to use `URI.encode(your_password, /\W/)` and use that as the redis_auth variable.

Comment: why is there a : after //

Comment: @Prime it's part of the general URI syntax.
URI = scheme:[//authority]path[?query][#fragment]
where authority =  [userinfo@]host[:port] and userinfo = username:password. Here the username is omitted (which redis will interpret as the 'default user') but the colon is still necessary to indicate the password portion is what follows.